# Bootstrap: container-fluid does not works

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on this [website](http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) (Builted using Wordpress and a Bootstrap template).

As you can see i have an header image  on top, into a `container-fluid`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/banner.png" width="100%">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But is alwasy displayed "boxed". How can i set this picture to fit the entire screen size?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you have the `container-fluid` inside another `container`. The markup by itself works fine:

http://www.codeply.com/go/mdyvvHY9Y0